# How to stop playing a sound initiated in AlarmManager in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, alarmmanager, dart-isolates

I'm currently writing an alarm clock app in Flutter and need to be able to start playing a custom sound at a specific time, even without the app currently running. I've already been able to achieve this with the following code (Using Android Alarm Manager Plus Flutter Package):

```
onTap() async {
    await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
                    const Duration(seconds: 5),
                    0,
                    playRingtone,
                    exact: true,
                    wakeup: true,
                  );
}
```

```
Future<void> playRingtone() async {
  await FlutterRingtonePlayer.play(
    fromAsset: "assets/song.mp3",
    looping: true, // Android only - API >= 28
    volume: 0.1, // Android only - API >= 28
    asAlarm: true, // Android only - all APIs
  );
}
```

For test purposes I'm firing an alarm 5 seconds from the point in time where the associated button is pressed. Now, here is where I run into a problem:
It turns out to be rather diffcult to *stop* playing that same sound.

The code that is supposed to stop the sound from playing

```
FlutterRingtonePlayer.stop();
AndroidAlarmManager.cancel(0);
```

is not doing much of anything. I run that code from another button tap somewhere else in the app. I suppose things are not working out because FlutterRingtonePlayer starts playing from an isolate/thread inside AlarmManager and so even if I kill the AlarmManager isolate/thread, the FlutterRingtonePlayer isolate (*inside* AlarmManager isolate) still keeps running.
Not sure though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer, which is actually quite simple: One needs to start another oneShot with AlarmManager using the same ID as before and simply stop the ringtone from there:

```
await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
                          const Duration(seconds: 0),
                          0, //This ID has to be the same as above
                          stopRingtone,
                          exact: true,
                          wakeup: true,
                        );
```

```
Future<void> stopRingtone() async {
  await FlutterRingtonePlayer.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the accepted answer is not work for me ,

the below code will work ( don't miss out `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` )

```
import 'dart:developer' as developer;
import 'package:android_alarm_manager_plus/android_alarm_manager_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter_ringtone_player/flutter_ringtone_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(const AlarmManagerExampleApp());
}

class AlarmManagerExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const AlarmManagerExampleApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        colorSchemeSeed: const Color(0x9f4376f8),
      ),
      home: const _AlarmHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class _AlarmHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const _AlarmHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AlarmHomePageState createState() => _AlarmHomePageState();
}

class _AlarmHomePageState extends State<_AlarmHomePage> {
  int alarmId = 1;

  Future<void> scheduleAlarm() async {
    await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
      const Duration(microseconds: 0),
      alarmId,
      callback,
      rescheduleOnReboot: true,
      exact: true,
      wakeup: true,
    );
  }

  Future<void> scheduleCancelAlarm() async {
    await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
      const Duration(microseconds: 0),
      alarmId,
      stopcallback,
      rescheduleOnReboot: true,
      exact: true,
      wakeup: true,
    );
  }

  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  static Future<void> callback() async {
    developer.log('Alarm fired!');
    FlutterRingtonePlayer.playAlarm(
      looping: true,
      asAlarm: false,
      volume: 1.0,
    );
  }

  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  static Future<void> stopcallback() async {
    developer.log('Alarm stop!');
    AndroidAlarmManager.cancel(1);
    FlutterRingtonePlayer.stop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Android alarm manager plus example'),
        elevation: 4,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              scheduleCancelAlarm();
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.stop),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Alarm fired  times',
              style: textStyle,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 24),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await scheduleAlarm();
              },
              child: const Text('Schedule OneShot Alarm'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but their was 500 millisecond delay